# how to add php tags with the dom parser

Tags: php, dom

I create some HTML Templates with php doms functionality,
now i like to add some php tags into my template
i.e.

```
$input = $this->dom->createElement('input');
$input->setAttribute("type", "text");
$input->setAttribute("name", $name);
$input->setAttribute("class", "input");
$input->setAttribute("id", $name);
$input->setAttribute("value", '<?=$foo->bar; ?>');
```

my problem is, that the dom parser escape the php line..

```
<input type="text" name="id" class="input" id="id" value="\&lt;?=$content-&gt;id;?&gt;" />
```

is there another way to do this ?

Comment: Just as a note, this seems like a *bad plan* from a security standpoint.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea. What do you want to do this for?

Comment: @syrion in which way this is a bad plan from a security standpoint ?!

Comment: It appears to me that you're attempting to set the value of a HTML form element to PHP code.  That value can be changed.  If you allow code to be executed from this form element, it can execute *arbitrary PHP statements* with the permissions that you have set for your script.  Deleting your site, for example.  Or pulling all of the information from your database.

Comment: yes, but this is exactly what i want to do.. to be honest i dont see there a real security issue, all i want to do is a echo of a php variable inside the html input field, this variable is checked twice before so dont mind about any security issue..

Comment: @syrion, Either I am missing something obvious, or I don't think you follow what is happening above.  I don't see the issue here.  He is trying to generate some HTML using the value output from `$foo->bar`.  What's the problem?

Comment: @Brad, look at his code.  As written, he's writing an `<input>` tag with a PHP block set as the value.  That's either a brain fart, as in it only needs to be `$input->setAttribute("value", $foo->bar);` in the first place, or it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @syrion, What, you've never set a default value to an input tag before?  It makes perfect sense, and you're right, it does only need to be `$input->setAttribute("value", $foo->bar);`, which I think is the problem here.

Comment: @Brad, Yes, I have.  I have never set the default value of a form element to be `<? $foo ?>`, though, which is what it looked like he was trying to do.  There is a distinct difference between setting the value of `$foo` as the default and actually setting `<? foo ?>` as the default.  *As written*, the OP's code looks like he's attempting to do the former.  Which is a terrible plan.

Comment: @nfo, Clarify for us, please.

Comment: In my last comment I should have said 'the latter, which is a terrible plan.'  Thinko.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [Processing Instruction](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createprocessinginstruction.php)

```
$php = $dom->createProcessingInstruction('php', 'echo $foo->bar;');
```

Full example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml('<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body/></html>');
$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->appendChild(
    $dom->createProcessingInstruction('php', 'echo $foo->bar;')
);
$dom->format = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $foo->bar;?>
  </body>
</html>
```