# Create playlist in flv player?

Tags: php, mysql, playlist

How can I create playlist in hd flv player ?

I have created table for playlist in mysql ?

But I can't able to fetch playlist in hd flv player.

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create playlist.xml add it in config.xml file in xml folder.

Refer this link for php in xml [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549645/php-code-inside-xml)