# How to load, modify and restore a PHP snippet using XPath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have PHP snippets like this (`snippet.php`):

```
<?php 
    $some_param = some_function();
?>

<p>
    Text, bla bla bla... <?php echo $some_param ?> other text
    more text
</p>
```

I load these snippets like this:

```
$html = file_get_contets('snippet.php');
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

and modify using xpath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//text()") as $q) {
    $str = trim($q->nodeValue);
    if (isset($strings[$str])) {
        $q->nodeValue = translate($str);
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to save this file:

```
$dom->save($out);
```

It destroys completly the snippet structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><?php
    $some_param = some_function();
??></head><body><p>
    Translated text, bla bla bla... &lt;?php echo $some_param ?&gt; other text
    more text
</p></body></html>
```

What can I do to restore the original snippet structure when saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP Snippets are [Processing Instructions](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi). You can query them with [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

```
//processing-instruction('php')
```

> The node test `text()` is true for any text node. For example, `child::text()` will select the text node children of the context node. Similarly, the node test `comment()` is true for any comment node, and the node test `processing-instruction()` is true for any processing instruction. The `processing-instruction()` test may have an argument that is Literal; in this case, it is true for any processing instruction that has a name equal to the value of the Literal.

How to add them to a document is explained in

- [how to add php tags with the dom parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247726/how-to-add-php-tags-with-the-dom-parser)

Comment: Processing Instructions are new to me. In the examples I can see how to create a new PHP instruction, but, how to load it? and what about the problem saving with the non-desired estructure that DOM parser adds?

Comment: @Ivan PIs are nodes, so you need to include them as such

Comment: Yes, but as you can see in the first example I put, PHP elements are mixed with HTML, how can I load it? Could put me an example, please?

Comment: if it exist, it contains a translation for a string. In the example, "Text, bla bla bla..." is translated to "Translated text, bla bla bla..."

Comment: @Ivan does it include the processing instructions?